# Why is this environment texture image showing only a solid color in the 3D view, using Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view

I'm having a problem rendering the environment map. I downloaded a sample project that has the same settings as my project but it renders without a problem. I tried using both a .hdr and .png image. Attached are screenshots with node settings. First is the incorrect render and 2nd image is the project the renders correctly. How do I go about fixing this?

[image: Incorrect render]

[image: Correct render]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That is because you are in orthographic view mode, toggle back to perspective mode with <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>.  Unless your camera is also set to orthographic you should always see the environment in camera view and your render.

Comment: Worked great. Thank you. I voted your answer up

Comment: @RandallRidley  Glad I could help!  To mark that this answer has satisfactorily answered your question you can click the green checkmark under the vote buttons to [accept it](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).  I don't think you can vote up [until you have 15 rep](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) (which you have now that I voted up your question).

Answer (score 3):

I accidentally used "Image texture" instead of "environment texture", which had a similar effect: the background looked like a single solid color only.

[image: Environment versus image texture]